# string user function

Tags: c#

how can i add a custom function to a string type

example:

```
string test = "hello";

test.userFn("world");

public string userFn(strng str) {
   return " " + str;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why a regular function would not be acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string userFn(this string str)
        {
            return " " + str;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a custom function, but you can use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to approximate this:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string userFn(this string str) {
         return " " + str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what framework you are using, if you are using 3.5, then yes you can add extensions to the String class, thereby extending it to include your methods/properties.
Have a look [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article445-extension-method-net-35-and-above.aspx) for an example of extending the String class.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

You should check .net 3.0 extension methods [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Microsoft example:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```